# PHP Soap "Caught exception: Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Since Soap errors are WSDL specific I'm asking this question. I'm trying to add a relation in an online accountancy application. Authenticating and getting works just fine.

This is the code I'm using (Security code and SessionID are working fine when Getting relations):

```
$params = array( "input" => array( "SecurityCode2" => $SecurityCode2,
    "SessionID" => $SessionID,
    "cRelatie" => array(
        "ID" => NULL,
        "AddDatum" => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"),
        "Code" => "PUBID".sprintf('%04d', $vve['id']),
        "Bedrijf" => $Bedrijf,
        "Contactpersoon" => $Contactpersoon
        )
    )
);
try {
    $response = $client->__soapCall("AddRelatie", $params);
}
catch (Exception $e){
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

I've also tried nesting the cRelatie within an array with one index called oRel (see WSDL), but that didn't work either.

Error:

> Caught exception: Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is the WSDL location
https://soap.e-boekhouden.nl/soap.asmx?wsdl

Answer (score 0):

Got it working:
There where non documented required fields
And date wasn't allowed to have time, In contrary to the WSDL

```
$params = array( "input" => array(
    "SecurityCode2" => $SecurityCode2,
    "SessionID" => $SessionID,
    "oRel" => array(
        "ID" => 0,
        "Gb_ID" => 0,
        "GeenEmail" => 0,
        "NieuwsbriefgroepenCount" => 0,
        "AddDatum" => date("Y-m-d"),
        "Code" => "PUBID".sprintf('%04d', $vve['id']),
        "Bedrijf" => $Bedrijf,
        "Contactpersoon" => $Contactpersoon
    )
));
```